# Ament_cmake BUILD_TESTING on by default?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found it surprising that `find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)` turns `BUILD_TESTING` on. Is this on purpose? Why? Does this go against the ROS2 principle of "if I don't use a feature, I shouldn't pay for it"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329930/ament_cmake-build_testing-on-by-default?/) by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2019-08-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ament_cmake` [exports a dependency on ament_cmake_test](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/be483fdcf62de7d89ea4107de2ea594804860ec4/ament_cmake/CMakeLists.txt#L19) which [adds the option BUILD_TESTING](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/be483fdcf62de7d89ea4107de2ea594804860ec4/ament_cmake_test/ament_cmake_test-extras.cmake#L19).  This matches [the CTest module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CTest.html) which *"automatically creates a `BUILD_TESTING` option that selects whether to enable testing support (`ON` by default)"*.

If `ament_cmake_test` isn't required, then calling `find_package()` on the individual `ament_cmake_*` packages needed by a project is the way to go. If `ament_cmake_test` is needed, the `BUILD_TESTING` option can be turned off on the command line with the cmake argument `-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF`. If you're using colcon, use `colcon build --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF`.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on 2019-08-02**:
Thanks, @sloretz! It explains a lot that this is an inherited convention :-).